# Counting rows with different values

Tags: mysql, rows

I have a table in mysql and I want this output:

```
HNSHAK  MOBILE COMPUTING =13
HNSHAK  STORAGE           =2
```

the product group will change each time I execute.

Table:

```
Productgroup    Created By
MOBILE COMPUTING    HNSHAK
MOBILE COMPUTING    HNSHAK
MOBILE COMPUTING    HNSHAK
MOBILE COMPUTING    HNSHAK
STORAGE             HNSHAK
MOBILE COMPUTING    HNSHAK
STORAGE             HNSHAK
MOBILE COMPUTING    HNSHAK
MOBILE COMPUTING    HNSHAK
MOBILE COMPUTING    HNSHAK
MOBILE COMPUTING    HNSHAK
MOBILE COMPUTING    HNSHAK
MOBILE COMPUTING    HNSHAK
MOBILE COMPUTING    HNSHAK
MOBILE COMPUTING    HNSHAK
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query should be this way:

```
SELECT `Created By`, ProductGroup, COUNT(*) `Count`
FROM tablename
GROUP BY `Created By`, ProductGroup;
```

using a `GROUP BY Created_By, ProductGroup` and the aggregate function `COUNT`.

This will give you:

```
Created By  ProductGroup           Count
HNSHAK      MOBILE COMPUTING        13
HNSHAK      STORAGE                 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `Created_By`, `Productgroup`, COUNT(`Productgroup`)
FROM `table_name`
GROUP BY `Productgroup`
```

You should use `GROUP BY` here. You should also keep in mind that if all of the values in `Created By` are not same (like one of them is, say, `COMPANY1`) then either you want to ignore the `Productgroup` and select first value of `Productgroup` that appears in the table or you'll have multiple rows of a Productgroup for each _manufacturer. To achieve the latter, you'll use `GROUP BY` this way

```
GROUP BY `Created_By`, `Productgroup`
```